# Cordova App - JPEG(Base64) Image Compression to Thumbnail Image Not working with windows 8.1 App?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova, image-compression

I am trying to compress JPEG(Base64) to Thumbnail Image into 256x192. But image showing blank after compression.

Below is my code

```
    createWindowsThumbImage = function (name, type, data_url, callback) {
    var img, canvas, context, result, dataURL;
    img   = document.createElement("img");

    img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data_url;
    canvas        = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width  = 256;
    canvas.height = 192;
    context       = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Fill the canvas with white color to avoid the transperent behaviour of png images
    context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 192);
   // Draw image with 256*192 dimention*/
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 256, 192);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(type);

    result = getFileData(type, dataURL);

    if (type === "image/jpeg") {
        name   = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".256x192.jpg";
    } else {
        name   = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".256x192.png";
    }
        callback({name: name, type: type, data: result.file_data});     
    };
```

Comment: Could you please also post the codes of `getFileData` function?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT
`getFileData = function (type, file_data) {
                var content = {};
                switch (type) {
                case "image/jpeg":
                    content.file_data = file_data.substr(23);
                    content.category = "image";
                    break;
                case "image/png":
                    content.file_data = file_data.substr(22);
                    content.category = "image";
                    break;
                }
                return content;
            };`

Comment: I made a sample from the codes but didn't reproduced the problem. Did you add `data:image/jpeg;base64,` string to the head of the data string? ex:`document.getElementById("myImage").src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + result.data`.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT after adding of `data:image/jpeg;base64` code working fine  on the windows tab or windows app, Image are showing perfectly. But, same code showing blank screen on windows phone.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. It works fine on my windows phone. Could you please try it on the emulator or some other device?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thank you. Okay I will try...

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT - Can you tell me the configuration of your Phone..